rviz2 error on ROS2 jazzy
Hello I got this error when I wanted to use rviz. Any one has any idea?
[ERROR] [1721492532.949638823] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 246)

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

From the installation troubleshoot:
If you using Linux, Try:
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb rviz2

That's solved my problem.
